# relative path to image doesnt display after website being deployed

Tags: angular

[   [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJszl.png)The image i have stored in my portfolio displays when served locally but after the website is deployed, it doesn't display. I am using the newest version of Angular f.y.i. What follows is snippet of the code i am using. It is an image on my pc that i have stored in an images folder which is located under the assets.

```
  <img alt="Kristopher Lea" src="../assets/images/KristopherLea2.jpg">
  <h3 class="city">Hometown:
    {{city}}
  </h3>
```

Comment: Can you show the error or any console issue you can see? Will help to answer the question better

Answer (score 1):

The image src should be looking like this:

```html
<img alt="Kristopher Lea" src="assets/images/KristopherLea2.jpg">
```

Or:

```html
<img alt="Kristopher Lea" src="/assets/images/KristopherLea2.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks. also, for every update that i save to the repository do i need to deploy afterwards?